# Merge two pandas dataframe based on conditional

Tags: python, pandas, join

The objective is to combine two `df` row wise, if a predetermine condition is met.
Specifically, if the difference between the column is less or equal than a `threshold`, then, join the row of the `df`.

Given two `df`: df1 and df2, the following code partially achieve the objective.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame ( {'time': [2, 3, 4, 24, 31]} )
df2 = pd.DataFrame (  {'time': [4.1, 24.7, 31.4, 5]} )
th = 0.9
all_comb=[]
for index, row in df1.iterrows ():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows ():
        diff = abs ( row ['time'] - row2 ['time'] )
        if diff <= th:
            all_comb.append({'idx_1':index,'time_1':row ['time'], 'idx_2':index2,'time_2':row2 ['time']})
df_all = pd.DataFrame(all_comb)
```

outputted

```
       idx_1  time_1  idx_2  time_2
0      2       4      0     4.1
1      3      24      1    24.7
2      4      31      2    31.4
```

However, the above approach ignore certain information i.e., the value of 2 and 3 from the `df1`, and the value of 5 from `df2`.

The expected output should be something like

```
idx_1  time_1  idx_2  time_2

0      2       NA    NA
1      3       NA    NA    
2       4      0     4.1
3      24      1    24.7
4      31      2    31.4
NA     NA      3     5
```

Appreciate for any hint or any way that more compact and efficient than the proposed above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can perform a cross merge and then subset all the rows at once based on your condition. Then we `concat`, adding back any rows that had no conditions met from both DataFrames.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = df1.reset_index().add_suffix('_1')
df2 = df2.reset_index().add_suffix('_2')

m = df1.merge(df2, how='cross')

# Subset to all matches: |time_diff| <= thresh
th = 0.9
m = m[(m['time_1'] - m['time_2']).abs().le(th)]

# Add back rows with no matches
res = pd.concat([df1[~df1.index_1.isin(m.index_1)],
                 m,
                 df2[~df2.index_2.isin(m.index_2)]], ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
print(res)
   index_1  time_1  index_2  time_2
0      0.0     2.0      NaN     NaN
1      1.0     3.0      NaN     NaN
2      2.0     4.0      0.0     4.1
3      3.0    24.0      1.0    24.7
4      4.0    31.0      2.0    31.4
5      NaN     NaN      3.0     5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the `cross`, never thought of that

Comment: If your DataFrames are large it can be prohibitively memory intensive, but the double loop over all rows will take forever anyway. For reasonable DataFrames where the cross will be <1B rows it should be plausible.

Answer (score 0):

[conditonal_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) handles inequality joins efficiently, without having to resort to cartesian joins, and should help with your use case:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df1 = (df1
      .astype({'time':float})
      .rename(columns={'time':'time_1'})
      .assign(idx_1=df1.index)
      )

df2 = (df2
      .assign(start = df2.time - th, 
              end = df2.time + th,
              idx_2=df2.index)
      .rename(columns={'time':'time_2'})
     )

(df1
.conditional_join(
    df2, 
    ('time_1','start','>='), 
    ('time_1','end','<='),
    how='outer', 
    df_columns="*_1", 
    right_columns="*_2")
) 
   time_1  idx_1  time_2  idx_2
0     2.0    0.0     NaN    NaN
1     3.0    1.0     NaN    NaN
2     4.0    2.0     4.1    0.0
3    24.0    3.0    24.7    1.0
4    31.0    4.0    31.4    2.0
5     NaN    NaN     5.0    3.0
```